# Grails GORM Dynamic Finders and Criteria Not Working For MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy, orm

My project's configuration is as follows:

- Groovy 2.3.7
- Grails 2.2.3
- Java 1.6.0_32
- MongoDB 2.6.5
- BuildConfig.groovy:

  - compile ":mongodb:1.3.3"

My domain class:

```
class Story {

    String url
    String content
    String status
    String title
}
```

In Grails Shell, I used the following commands:
    Story.withCriteria { eq("url","url") }
    Story.findByUrl("url")

They both returned empty.

In Mongo shell:

```
> db.story.find()
{ "_id" : NumberLong(2), "categories" : [ null, null ], "content" : "content", "status" : "status", "title" : "title", "url" : "url", "version" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "_id" : NumberLong(3), "categories" : [ null, null ], "content" : "content1", "status" : "status1", "title" : "title1", "url" : "url1", "version" : 0 }
{ "_id" : NumberLong(4), "categories_$$manyToManyIds" : [ NumberLong(1), NumberLong(2) ], "category" : NumberLong(1), "content" : "content1", "status" : "status1", "title" : "title1", "url" : "url1", "version" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "_id" : NumberLong(5), "content" : "content1", "status" : "status1", "title" : "title1", "url" : "url1", "version" : 0 }
```

My question is why the grails dynamic finders and criteria didn't return anything. Please help me if you have any clues.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. All you need to do is to exit from your grails shell and restart it.

Comment: feel free to delete this quesion

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Hi, how can I remove this question? I looked around but there is no facility to do this.

Comment: It might only be visible once you have a high enough reputation.